# django check_password return false with correct password

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

i have this custom user with email backend and as you can see i'm using set_password before saving but its still not matching with correct password on this user.check_password(password) in emailbackend and i'm creating user with drf

backend.py:

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    try:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    else:
        print('this is user right', user, password)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    return None
```

serializers.py:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
              'mobile_number', 'password', 'is_active', 'user_type', 'otp')

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = CustomUser(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        mobile_number=validated_data['mobile_number'],
        first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
        user_type=validated_data['user_type'],
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: solved.................

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @hedgie i was comparing with wrong password